# How to turn data from Text to Variable in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, variables, text

edit: I want to use that variables which I want to extract from a txt file as input for my code. So I need them as a variable.

I have 2 python script, first one get data as .txt file and the file content is like this;

```
posrobdone = 2258, 1016
posnight = 2258, 1016
posenter = 2258, 1016
posbuy = 2258, 1016
posrobbery = 2258, 1016
```

And than in my second script read this text file and get these datas as variables like for example when I write;

```
print(posnight)
```

I wanted to see output as;

> 2258, 1016

However whatever I do, I cannot figured it out how to extract these datas from this text file. Whatever I do, it gives me error like

> NameError: name 'posnight' is not defined

When I try this;

```
with open("positions.txt", "r") as f:
    positions = f.read()

print(positions)
print(posnight)
```

I can get output and error like this;

```
posrobdone = 2258, 1016
posnight = 2258, 1016
posenter = 2258, 1016
posbuy = 2258, 1016
posrobbery = 2258, 1016

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gamer/OneDrive/Masaüstü/crimsbot/crimsbot.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(posnight)
NameError: name 'posnight' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I even get them and turn to a list with append but not worked for me. I'm kinda beginner in this coding thing, I'm actually more into the computer vision field however I wanted to improve myself with these small projects and challenges. So if you can help me to solve this, I would be very happy and glad.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: The contents of your file is just text. A big string of characters. Opening and reading characters from a file doesn't magically create Python variables.

Answer (score 3):

Collect the info into a dictionary.  Don't try to create variables from variable data.

```
from pprint import pprint

data = """\
posrobdone = 2258, 1016
posnight = 2258, 1016
posenter = 2258, 1016
posbuy = 2258, 1016
posrobbery = 2258, 1016"""


collect = {}
for line in data.splitlines():
    parts = line.strip().split()
    collect[parts[0]] = int(parts[2][:-1]), int(parts[3])

pprint(collect)
print(collect['posnight'])
```

Output:

```
{'posbuy': (2258, 1016),
 'posenter': (2258, 1016),
 'posnight': (2258, 1016),
 'posrobbery': (2258, 1016),
 'posrobdone': (2258, 1016)}
(2258, 1016)
```

Note that it's easy to change the `for` line to `for line in open('positions.txt'):`.

Comment: So I have 1 more question, how can I get that data = "green" part from that text file? I want my second script works directly from that text file created by first one. Thank you for your helping. Also I wanted to use that posnight, posbuy etc variable in a loop.

Comment: You have never mentioned anything about `data = "green"`, nor have you mentioned having two scripts, so I don't know what you mean.  You CAN use those variables in a loop -- just write `collect['posnight']`.